# Does radiation from other stars reach the earth?

Tags: science-based, planets, radiation

I don't know much about astronomy or science or physics but can radiation from other stars reach earth?

If so, then can radiation from our sun and radiation from the other stars mix or combine to form new radiation? And finally can radiations from **Acrux** star and **Deneb** star reach earth?

Comment: An excellent question for Astronomy SE or Physics SE. But rather off-topic for Worldbuilding. (The answer, by the way, is 'yes...but very very little'. That's why you can see them only at night as tiny specks)

Comment: The answers to your questions are as follows: yes, no, yes.

Comment: Yes, of course.  Otherwise we couldn't see them :-)

Answer (score 10):

Yes. It's called light.

Visible light is a very small part of the ElectroMagnetic Spectrum, the whole of which we call radiation. In that regard, the fact that we can see these stars in the night sky tells us that we can receive their radation per se.

The real question I think you're asking is can it do us damage? If so, then the answer is no.

First of all, these stars are very far away. We can see their light in the dark night sky, but we can't read by it, for instance. The lumen count is nowhere near high enough for that. Most of the really dangerous radiation from these stars would be filtered out by the atmosphere or the Earth's magnetic field; it would be in such small quantities in any event it's not really dangerous. Our own star is FAR more dangerous to us (because of its proximity) and is one of the key limitations to long term human space habitation.

There's one exception to this rule; supernovas.

Supernovas created by the death of a star even remotely close to our location in the Galaxy would be devastating, because of the sheer volume of radiation and debris being generated. There's a theory that all of the major planetary extinction events in the Earth's history coincide with a time when the Z axis wobble of the solar system has brought it through the main line of the galactic spiral we're part of, and either triggered asteroids, super novas, etc.

So, Yes - Acrux and Deneb's radiation reaches us, but not in a manner we should consider dangerous or even impactful in any way. In terms of it mixing or combining, there is nothing 'unique' to the radiation from such stars that could cause any effects on earth, especially inside the atmosphere. Besides, resonance effects notwithstanding, radiation mechanics are very different to those in chemistry; you can't 'mix' Gamma radiation with X-Rays to get some new Radiation 'compound' with completely new qualities. The most interesting effect that could occur is that some of the radiation would 'cancel out' other waves that came along with inverse coherence, but that would be extremely rare. Given we're talking about such a small amount of radiation to begin with, the effect is less than negligible.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt Well the answer to that is very simple: no. Radiation doesn't combine. Radiation isn't a substance you can combine like paint, it consists of individual particles - photons - which have a specific wave length, the latter dictating the former's properties. You can send photons towards each other but they'll just pass right through each other, no mixing or combining at all.